# Redirection from index to a post fails while solving prevention duplicate vote

Tags: python, django, django-templates, django-views

I want to save the votes of an user of each post in order to prevent duplicate vote. The idea is to save the upvotes in 'liked_eintraege'. The user should only be able to vote on the result page, not index page. Hence I added it to the result view.

Currently if you upvote a post, the points go up but the problem ist that it keeps redirecting to this (upvoted) post, no matter on what post I click on the index page. However duplicate vote is not possible because it goes to the else clause and doesn't show the vote triangle. So prevention of duplicate vote works.

views.py

```
def result(request, id):
    eintrag = get_object_or_404(Eintrag, pk=id)

    ...

    eintraege = Eintrag.objects.all().order_by('-id')       
    if request.user.is_authenticated():
       #here in the next line is the problem:
       liked_eintraege = request.user.liked_eintraege.filter(id__in=[eintrag.id for eintrag in eintraege])
    else:
        liked_eintraege=[] 

    context = {
    'eintrag': eintrag,
    'comments': comments,
    'comment_form':form,
    'liked_eintraege': liked_eintraege
    }

    return render(request, 'gaestebuch/result.html', context)

@login_required
def vote(request):
    eintrag = get_object_or_404(Eintrag, pk=request.POST.get('eintrag'))
    eintrag.points += 1
    eintrag.save()
    user = request.user
    user.liked_eintraege.add(eintrag)
    user.save()
    return HttpResponse()
```

models.py:

```
class Eintrag(models.Model):
    author = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, default=1)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    points = models.IntegerField(default=1)
    text = models.TextField()
    created_date = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    voters = models.ManyToManyField(User, related_name='liked_eintraege')
```

and in result.html:

```
            {% if user.is_authenticated and eintrag not in liked_eintraege %}
                <a href="/vote/" id="eintrag-vote-{{ eintrag.id }}" class="vote">▲</a>
                <p id="eintrag-title-{{ eintrag.id }}">{{ eintrag.title }}</p>
            {% else %}
                <p>{{ eintrag.title }}</p>
            {% endif %}
```

the vote function works, thanks to a previous post I already did.

Comment: So what's the question?

Comment: Have you tried a bolean field in Eintrag model that updates to true when the user make his first vote so he can't do it again ?

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but couldn't you just do `... eintrag not in user.liked_eintrage`?   (or is it `user.liked_eintrage_set.all`)  -- my point is the attribute `user.liked_eintrage` is already filtered by the `user`.

Comment: no I'm still facing the same issue. Once I voted on a post, I kept redirecting to it from the index page, no matter on what post I click.

Comment: hey I just updated my question, perhaps it is now clearer. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This fixed my problem!

```
liked_eintraege = request.user.liked_eintraege.all()
```

instead of filtering it (filter(id__in=[eintrag.id for eintrag in eintraege])), because the template already does this! Thanks anyway.